# Why am I getting We are no longer accepting questions from this account

Tags: support

Getting

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See
>   http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

I seriously do not think my question was that bad? Also this link is for meta.stackoverflow
I am an active member of many other stackexchange sites and seriously think that it's very harsh. Is there any thing I can do about it.

Answer (score 8):

You've asked 6 questions, 5 of which have been deleted or migrated away from the site. Because of this, your account has had an automatic ban from asking questions placed on it.

The [FAQ entry on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this) goes into more detail about why you might've received this ban, so I'll just quote the last part, on getting the ban lifted:

> #### How long do I have to wait before I can ask questions again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Question bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time to ask your next question. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to ask questions again.
>
> If you tripped the heuristic by just a tiny bit, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure. And even if you're lucky then you're still very close to being banned again, if you get new downvotes.
>
> If you really, *really* think the question ban is an error, then email the team directly at the address provided at the bottom of every page. But note that Stack Overflow alone gets more than 3,000 questions per day, so a few rejected questions won't be missed. Therefore, reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).
>
> #### Can I simply create a new account?
>
> No. The question ban is at [a lower level than account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).